# Decrement variable in one in a funtion called multiple times

Tags: javascript, decrement

So i have this asignment where you need to substract a life from a player when he is hit in a little javascript game, each time he is hit `die()` is called, the problem is that the program detects multiple hits that should account for just one life, here is the code, there is a variable called lives that is initialized with 3 once lives reaches zero the game should end:

```
die() {
    if (!this.dead) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.game.endGame();
        }, 2000);
        super.die();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to explore event loop in javascript.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @nicknackd. Right now there is little to go on to fix your code. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to run your code and to test it. Otherwise there is not much we can do.